# Vue selected option

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to change the selected option on page load. When the page is loaded and new or used is not null the I want which ever on that is not null to be selected instead of it alway selecting status. I have tried many things and nothing has worked and have not been able to fin much online about how to make this work.

I have tried it with and without v-bind, without v-model, and other ways that I saw online.

```
<select id="application-status" class="custom-select" v-model="selected">
  <option :value="null" disabled>Status</option>
  <option :value="'new'" v-bind:selected="item.new != null">New</option>
  <option :value="'used'" v-bind:selected="item.used != null">Used</option>
</select>
```

Right no no matter what Status always shows up.

Comment: let `this.selected='new'` in mounted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value of `selected` in some manner.  One way is, as [Sphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5665870/sphinx) pointed out [in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50801866/691711#comment-88609731), is to use a `mounted()` lifecycle hook:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  mounted() {
    this.selected = "used";
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selected: "",
      item: "new"
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select id="application-status" class="custom-select" v-model="selected">
    <option :value="null" disabled>Status</option>
    <option :value="'new'" v-bind:selected="item.new != null">New</option>
    <option :value="'used'" v-bind:selected="item.used != null">Used</option>
  </select>
</div>
```